# Como converter um valor Decimal para Datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão-de-tipo, decimal

Alguém pode me ajudar com a seguinte dúvida?

Tenho retorno de duas variavéis. Exemplos:

- 1ª - do tipo `decimal` (`vdecTotalHoras`) e a
- 2ª - também do tipo `decimal` (`vdecMediaAnalise`), ambas retornam valores de data e hora em `decimal`. Como converto para `DateTime`?

O código abaixo demonstra como estou recebendo os valores:

```
(
    decTotalHoras = ((paintHoras * 60) + paintMinutos) / 60;
    decMediaAnalise = (decTotalHoras) / paintAnalises;
)
```

Mas não consigo converter os retornos para Hora/Minuto/Segundo.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida. Diga com mais clareza o seu problema, onde quer chegar, e se possível o que tentou fazer. Você tem a quantidade de segundos? Pra mim essas variáveis que usou no exemplo estão muito soltas, sem contexto. Aproveite explique o é retorno para você, já que variável não retorna nada, elas apenas possuem valores.

Comment: Você está trabalhando apenas com horas e minutos. Não faz muito sentido usar um `DateTime`. Acho que o seu caso [estaria mais para um `TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o que faria mais sentido é a conversão para um **Intervalo de tempo** (`TimeSpan`). Se for isso você pode usar o trecho abaixo:

```
TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(decimalValue));
```

Caso contrário pode tentar o seguinte:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(decimalValue);
```

Porém nunca usei a segunda forma e não sei como ela se comportaria.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, coverti a minha variavél em TimeSpan e funcionou.

Comment: Se funcionou não esqueça de sinalizar como resposta.